CMake appears to add include libraries from interface library, but they're not accessible in VS2022
I'm trying to use CMake v3.30.5 to create a C++ project building with VS2022. I would like to include 3rd party code via FetchContent so I do not need to add them to my source tree. The code will be placed in a directory called SDKs in the project root and consumed by a project Core also placed in the root. For the first one, I want to add FastDelegate (https://github.com/dreamcat4/FastDelegate) as a header-only library, so I've declared it INTERFACE since it doesn't compile any sources.
My root CMakeLists.txt looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

project(MyProj
    LANGUAGES CXX
    VERSION 0.0.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake")
set(SDK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDKs")
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

add_subdirectory(SDKs)
add_subdirectory(Core)

The SDKs CMakeLists.txt successfully grabs the source, places it in the SDKs/FastDelegate folder, and runs find_package as I expect:
include (FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(FastDelegate
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/dreamcat4/FastDelegate.git
        GIT_PROGRESS true
        SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FastDelegate"
        BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/SDKs/FastDelegate"
        FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(FastDelegate)

The FindFastDelegate.cmake for find_package creates an INTERFACE library with the headers and sets the include directory:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

set(SRC_DIR "${SDK_DIR}/FastDelegate")

add_library(FastDelegate INTERFACE
    "${SRC_DIR}/FastDelegate.h"
    "${SRC_DIR}/FastDelegateBind.h")
add_library(SDK::FastDelegate ALIAS FastDelegate)
target_include_directories(FastDelegate INTERFACE ${SRC_DIR})
set_target_properties(FastDelegate PROPERTIES FOLDER "SDKs/FastDelegate")

and my Core CMakeLists.txt links to the FastDelegate INTERFACE library:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

add_library(Core STATIC
    Core_defines.h) 
set_target_properties(Core PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(Core PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(Core
    PUBLIC
        SDK::FastDelegate)

# added this to make sure include directories are correct
file(GENERATE OUTPUT "$<CONFIG>output.txt"
    CONTENT "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Core,INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>")

The test output does indeed show that the include directories for the Core library are
C:/Projects/MyProj/Core;C:/Projects/MyProj/SDKs/FastDelegate as I would expect. However, the MSVC project does not list either of those in the include directories and I cannot #include the FastDelegate files.
Have I missed something or done something wrong, or is there an issue with CMake?

How does the command line look like? Project properties->C/C++->Command Line. Or just the "Additional Include Directories" option from  "General"

The additional include directories only has the default values in it: $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);. However, I do notice that there is no C/C++ section in the project properties, but they do appear in other unrelated self-contained test projects within this solution. The only real differences between them I can tell is that those projects 1) have source (.cpp) files and 2) are executables rather than libraries. I'll try adding a source file to my project and see if that doesn't change things.

@ixSci yeah looks like that was it. If there are no source files in the project, either CMake or VS (not sure which) doesn't bring in the include directories. Now the project shows the C/C++ options, shows the include directories, and I can #include the file. Thanks for asking the question!

Thanks to @ixSci for asking the good question that lead me on the path:
My Core library that was linking to the INTERFACE library did not have any source files in it, only other headers, so there was no compilation output. This causes either CMake or VS (not sure which) to not bring in the additional include directories. Once I added an empty TestSource.cpp into Core and ran CMake again, the include directories appear in the project properties as I expect and I can #include the headers in my files.
